# free voice activated sound recording software

Tags: voip

I connected my PBX to the sound card of my Windows XP PC, using a special interface hardware.  I want to record all the sound into MP3 format. Please reccomend a free software that can record only when voice activated.

thank you very much, Nathaniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Audacity Beta has this feature, never used it though.

http://wiki.audacityteam.org/index.php?title=VoiceActivated

Download page
http://audacity.sourceforge.net/